# Why does using csh -e option succeed on the command line, but fail in a jenkins execute shell?

Tags: jenkins, csh

I am using jenkins to build a bunch of legacy code. The legacy code comes with some complex build scripts, written in csh.

The build scripts do not check for or exit on errors. The user is expected to scan the output for error messages. However, this does not work well with Jenkins.

I am executing the csh build scripts in a jenkins "shell execution" build step. For example:

```
export PATH=`pwd`/ALL/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH
cd ATLb2.00/expt_02.0
csh 020.com
```

When I run this from the command line, I can also use the -e option:

```
csh -e 020.com
```

In this case, as I expect, the script is run, but when the first error is encountered, the script stops and returns a non-zero code. However, when I try this in Jenkins, the build fails as soon as it gets to the csh -e command, without executing any of the script.

The error I get in Jenkins is:

```
+ csh -e 020.com
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

On the command line, the script is run and I see all kinds of output, until something fails, and then the script exits. On Jenkins the script seems to fail without even running. There is no output, and even scripts with no failures will not run for me under jenkins with the -e option.

What's up?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you specify csh on a more global level and then execute the commands in a Jenkins build step.

If you want to use csh for all jobs, you can set the default shell using *Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > shell executable*.

If you want to use csh for only a particular job, begin the *Execute shell* build step with a shebang, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -e -x
command1
command2
   ...
```

Since I have tested only tcsh, that is what I use in the example.

**Beware that a space is not allowed** after the `#!`:

```
#!  /usr/bin/tcsh    # Wrong
```

This will give the error,

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""
```

I tested the above on Jenkins 1.625.3

Comment: Are these `#!` lines interpreted by Jenkins? In normal usage, where the `#!` is interpreted by the kernel, a space *is* allowed after the `#!` -- and you typically can't have more than one argument after the command name (`#!/usr/bin/tcsh -ex` should work).

Comment: It is Java that complains that it cannot execute the program "".  This empty string is what appears between `#!` and the white space that follows.  Thus I presume that Jenkins is interpreting this.  
You have an excellent point about about the multiple options.  I should take a closer look at whether they are really both having effect.